# Как сгенерировать private key через openssl?

Tags: windows, криптография, openssl, key

Нужно сгенерировать ключи для платежной системы, дело в том, что я даже приблизительно не знаю как это сделать.

Коллега, который знает как это сделать, сказал что это нужно делать через openssl и скинул следующие параметры

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

Я пользуюсь windows, правильно ли я понимаю что мне нужно скачать openssl и дальше в консоле запустить эти команды, которые сгенерируют мне 2 файла.

Ну вот я скачал openssl, зашел в консоль, и ничего не срабатывает. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь написать пошагово, что мне нужно сделать? А то сколько бы я не гуглил, яснее не стало.

Я так понимаю, что нужно в консоле идентифицировать openssl?

Comment: Он вам команды для консоли linux скинул.

Comment: Ну под windows openssl аналогично работает. А что такое "не срабатывает" он же должен какую то ошибку выдавать. Если не находит саму утилиту openssl, значит она у вас не в путях и надо это делать в папке куда установлена openssl или явно указать путь к ней

Comment: Выводит ошибку 'openssl' is invalid command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Скачиваем установочный дистрибутив openssl-1.1.1g](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

2. Устанавливаем OpenSSL в C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
3. Прописываем переменные среды:

   - В поиске window вводим "изменение системных переменных среды" -> переменные среды -> в окошке системные переменные добавляем переменную
     OPENSSL_CONF, прописываем в ней путь: C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
   - В этом же окошке находим Path, в конец добавляем C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin.
4. После этого проверьте установку openSSL. Откройте командную строку и введите openssl version. Если появится версия, то все ок.
5. Теперь можете использовать те команды, которые скинул вам коллега.